# Drag-and-drop problem in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nautilus, zip, drag-and-drop, 23.04

I am frequently downloading *zip* or *rar* archive files from the Web to extract their contents into a folder. There are two applications on my system that handle these type of archive files: **Archive Manager** and **Xarchiver**. Both have the same problem:

- Download a compressed file from Web (this step is irrelevant, the compressed file may already be on local disk too);
- The compressed archive opens in one of the above-mentioned applications;
- Select a file or some files from the archive and try to drag and drop them into a folder which is open in **Nautilus**;
- No action is taken and the animation shows that the file cannot be saved here.

If I use **Thunar** (under Xorg) instead of **Nautilus**, I don't have this problem.

I have tested in *Xorg* and *Wayland* sessions and both do not work; in Wayland even the **Thunar** alternative does not seem to work.

Previously posted similar Questions in Ask Ubuntu do not work in Ubuntu 23.04. Is there some hidden option or trick that will help?

Note that drag-and-drop within Nautilus or some other desktop applications (for example, between **Thunderbird** and **Nautilus**) *does* work. It may be the problem with these archive managers.

A recommendation for an *archive manager* that has no drag-and-drop problem with **Nautilus** may also help.

Comment: I wonder whether you are actually uncompressing the archives or simply viewing their contents? If they are not uncompressed, it would explain the problem.

Comment: These are compressed txt files in a rar or zip archive and I want to copy these txt files into a folder by dragging and dropping into the folder which is open in Nautilus. If the same folder is open in Thunar drag-and-drop works.